# Why cannot others see my app/use my app

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook canvas app. It embeds a web site (which is fully functioning for several months).

If I paste the app url in browser, only I can see the app. But when any of my friends type  https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, they are not able to/allowed to see the page. Even when they are logged in as facebook user, they are not allowed to see the app page.

(I have implemented facebook login using javascript in my home page)

Can anyone give any hints.

Comment: Is the application in test mode/sandbox mode? Has it been published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Settings & Review" in the App Settings, there is a checkbox to put the App live. Else, only users with a role in the App can use it.